# May a seller offer a reward on a sale, which he explicitly limits only to cash (not credit) sales?

Tags: halacha, lending-interest-ribbis, transactions

It is forbidden to explicitly set two tiered pricing for sales, A lower price for cash payment & a higher price for credit (delayed) payment. The additional payment for credit is considered *ribbis* interest, as it is a payment for delaying the owed funds. (Mishnah BM 65b & Shulchan Aruch YD 173)
Question: May a seller offer a reward on a sale, which he explicitly limits only to cash sales. Is the buyer's forfeiting the receipt of the reward in exchange for delayed payment considered *ribbis*?

NOTE: I am reffering to a situation where charging more for delayed payment would be FORBIDDEN. My question is whether forfeiting the receipt of a gift given for cash payments is considered ribbis. If a certain situation would allow charging more for credit (or credit cards), that is not in my question.

Comment: This question was answered here: http://dinonline.org/2018/07/04/may-a-seller-offer-a-reward-on-a-sale-which-he-explicitly-limits-only-to-cash-not-credit-sales/

Comment: @IsraelReader If you will read the answer there, you will see that the answer given simply does not answer the question asked.

Comment: If you feel that they erred, why don't you leave them a comment there? I was actually impressed by their analyses, though there appears to be an error there in the wording. "Therefore when the lender ( the customer) pays extra, it appears to be ribbis." Should read: Therefore when the BORROWER ( the customer) pays extra, it appears to be ribbis.

Comment: @IsraelReader First I will respond to your correction of their wording. They DID write " Therefore when **the borrower (the customer)** pays extra, it appears to be ribbis." They are right!, You misquoted the wording.

Comment: @IsraelReader  The problem I ppointed out is is that they go on to write that if the owner gives the customer a gift there is no problem because the lender is giving the borrower a gift so no ribbis. That was never the question! The question was if the seller only offers to give the cash payers a  gift, and NOT to the credit customers, then the credit customer. is FORFEITING the gift! Is THAT called ribbis? This they did not answer at all.

Comment: I did NOT misquote their wording. I sent them the original wording, and my correction. They realized that I was right, and corrected it, without any acknowledgement. Meanwhile, my comment still gets the message: "Your comment is awaiting moderation."

Comment: If you feel that they erred, why don't you leave them a comment there? According to you, where is the "Neshech" or "Tarbis"? מניעת קבלת מתנה???

Comment: @IsraelReader -  If **I** feel??? What do you think? Did they answer the question asked?? That was the essentially what was asked -  Is מניעת קבלת מתנה  on behalf of the borrower, when the lender saves from it, considered ריבית or not?

Comment: I already wrote, that I was impressed by their analyses. You are the "Ribbis Rabbi", so I asked you where is the "Neshech" or "Tarbis"? You have none here. So question answered. There is no infraction of the Torah here.

Comment: Check out what they responded to you.